# How to list users in all domains running code from a non-domain computer?

Tags: c#, authentication, active-directory, windows-authentication, directoryservices

I have 2 domains with trusts between them. I have a single Active Directory account in one of these domains that also has permissions in in another domain because of the configured trust. In my application I need to access both domains and list users in them.

My development computer is NOT in the above domains and I cannot add it to these domains.
Currently I am using the following code to list users on the domain in which my account was created:

```
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "192.168.2.11", “Login1”, “pass1”))
{
    using (UserPrincipal searchPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(pc))
    {
         searchPrincipal.Name = "*";
         using (PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(searchPrincipal))
         {

                using (PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> principals = searcher.FindAll())
                {
                     foreach (UserPrincipal principal in principals)
                      {
                          Console.WriteLine(principal.Name);
                      }
                }
         }
    }
}
```

How do I adapt my code to list users from both domains in case I run it on a computer that is not in one of these domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple choices.

1. If both domains are in the same Forest you could just query the Global Catalog by changing the Domain IP to the Global Catalog IP.

[C# - Searching for users across multiple Active Directory domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967871/c-sharp-searching-for-users-across-multiple-active-directory-domains)

2. Continue with your hardcoded approach you could create an array of domain IPs. Iterate through the array and call your code for each one in the array.

string[] domains = new string[] {"192.168.2.11","192.168.2.12"};

```
        for(int i = 0; i < domains.Length; i++)
        {
            using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domains[i], “Login1”, “pass1”))
            {
                using (UserPrincipal searchPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(pc))
                {
                     searchPrincipal.Name = "*";
                     using (PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(searchPrincipal))
                     {

                            using (PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> principals = searcher.FindAll())
                            {
                                 foreach (UserPrincipal principal in principals)
                                  {
                                      Console.WriteLine(principal.Name);
                                  }
                            }
                     }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the useful link. I realized that I need to somehow discover the domains and than list users in each domain (the required user info is stored on a domain level and not in a Global Catalog), I asked another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27908447/how-to-list-domains-running-code-from-a-non-domain-computer