# Generic way to search all users within an organisation using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to figure out how to return all users with email addresses in an organization using **System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement**, however I want to do it without having to specify the domain.

This is to be used in a windows service that will be installed on a server PC within the organization and ideally I don't want each client to have to enter in their domain when installing.

Currently I use the following:

```
context = New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain)

Using userPrin As New UserPrincipal(context)
    userPrin.Enabled = True
    userPrin.EmailAddress = "*"
    Using searcher = New PrincipalSearcher(New UserPrincipal(context))
        searcher.QueryFilter = userPrin

        Using results As PrincipalSearchResult(Of Principal) = searcher.FindAll
            Trace.WriteLine("results.count: " & results.Count)
            userPrincipalResult = (From r In results Select TryCast(r, UserPrincipal))
            Trace.WriteLine("userPrincipalResult.Count: " & userPrincipalResult.Count)
            userList = (From cr In userPrincipalResult Select cr.EmailAddress).ToList()
        End Using

    End Using
End Using
```

The problem with this is that if the main domain is `@client.com`, but they have another domain `@clientdifferent.com` within the same forest, then it doesn't return any users from this other domain.

I have found posts that explain you can search GC instead of LDAP to search at a higher level, however this requires adding the domain and port number.  Is there any way to do a similar thing without having to specify any domain?

Links:

[How to search in multiple domains using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459477/how-to-search-in-multiple-domains-using-system-directoryservices-accountmanageme)

[When do I need a Domain Name and a Domain Container to create a PrincipalContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23559710/when-do-i-need-a-domain-name-and-a-domain-container-to-create-a-principalcontext)

[C# - Searching for users across multiple Active Directory domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967871/c-sharp-searching-for-users-across-multiple-active-directory-domains)

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work:

```
Using tempForest = ActiveDirectory.Forest.GetCurrentForest()
    For Each domain As ActiveDirectory.Domain In tempForest.Domains
        context = New PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain.Name)
        Using userPrin As New UserPrincipal(context)
            userPrin.Enabled = True
            userPrin.EmailAddress = "*"
            Using searcher = New PrincipalSearcher(New UserPrincipal(context))
                searcher.QueryFilter = userPrin

                Using results As PrincipalSearchResult(Of Principal) = searcher.FindAll
                    Trace.WriteLine("results.count: " & results.Count)
                    userPrincipalResult = (From r In results Select TryCast(r, UserPrincipal))
                    Trace.WriteLine("userPrincipalResult.Count: " & userPrincipalResult.Count)
                    userList = (From cr In userPrincipalResult Select cr.EmailAddress).ToList()
                End Using

            End Using
        End Using
    Next
End Using
```